# create a pandas dataframe from a nested xml file

Tags: python, xml, pandas, lxml

Here is a **small section** of an xml file. I would like to create a database from this with each tag unique columns names and non-duplicated data.

Tried using lxml and the best I have been able to do so far is to create a dataframe that results in something like this:

```
"    
SRCSGT
DATE    11112017
AGENCY  Department of Veterans Affairs
OFFICE  Canandaigua VAMC   
LOCATION    Department of Veterans Affairs Medical Center
ZIP 14424
etc, etc, "
```

### The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NOTICES>
  <SRCSGT>
    <DATE>11112017</DATE>
    <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs]]></AGENCY>
    <OFFICE><![CDATA[Canandaigua VAMC]]></OFFICE>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs Medical Center]]></LOCATION>
    <ZIP>14424</ZIP>
    <CLASSCOD>H</CLASSCOD>
    <NAICS>238210</NAICS>
    <OFFADD><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs;400 Fort Hill Ave.;Canandaigua NY  14424]]></OFFADD>
    <SUBJECT><![CDATA[H--3 YEAR TESTING/MAINTENANCE OF ELECTRICAL EQUIPMENT AT THE SYRACUSE VA MEDICAL CENTER AND THE ROME COMMUNITY BASED OUTPATIENT CLINIC  ]]></SUBJECT>
    <SOLNBR><![CDATA[9069]]></SOLNBR>
    <RESPDATE>11172017</RESPDATE>
    <ARCHDATE>12172017</ARCHDATE>
    <CONTACT><![CDATA[COiyiyS, JUhhiuN<a href="mailto:Juggyui@va.gov">CONTRACT SPECIALIST</a>]]></CONTACT>
    <DESC><![CDATA[This is a Sources Sought Notice. (a) The Government does not intend to award a contract on the basis of this Sources Sought or to otherwise pay for the information solicited.(b) Although "proposal," "offeror," contractor, and "offeror" may be used in this sources sought notice, any response will be treated as information only. It shall not be used as a proposal.Attachment(s) if applicable. ]]></DESC>
    <LINK><![CDATA[https://www.fbo.gov/spg/VA/CaVAMC532/CaVAMC532/9069/listing.html]]></LINK>
    <EMAIL>
      <ADDRESS><![CDATA[Jigjhgjas@va.gov]]></ADDRESS>
      <DESC><![CDATA[CONTRACT SPECIALIST]]></DESC>
    </EMAIL>
    <SETASIDE>N/A</SETASIDE>
    <RECOVERY_ACT>N</RECOVERY_ACT>
    <DOCUMENT_PACKAGES>
      <PACKAGE><![CDATA[Attachment]]></PACKAGE>
    </DOCUMENT_PACKAGES>
  </SRCSGT>
</NOTICES>
```

---

### code I wrote

```
from lxml import etree as et
import pandas as pd

trees = et.parse('test.xml') #get xml file
root = trees.getroot() #get to root of file

tags = [] #list for holding all tags
datas = [] #list for holding all data in tags


for child in root: #root is a list of all elements in the xml file
    #print(child.tag)
    tt = child.tag #reads xml tag
    tags.append(tt)
    datas.append(child.text) #read xml tag data
    for c in child.findall('./'): # ./ finds children
        tt1 = c.tag
        tags.append(str(tt1))
        datas.append(c.text)
        for i in c.findall('./'): #each child node loads a new list of elements
            tt2 = i.tag
            tags.append(str(tt1)+ '_' + str(tt2))
            datas.append(i.text)
            for j in i.findall('./'):
                tt3 = j.tag
                tags.append(str(tt1)+ '_' + str(tt2) + '_' + str(tt3))
                datas.append(j.text)
                for k in j.findall('./'):
                    tt4 = k.tag
                    tags.append(str(tt1)+ '_' + str(tt2) + '_' + str(tt3) + '_' + str(tt4))
                    datas.append(k.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"tags": tags,"values": datas})
```

---

The desired solution is something like this

```
 date agency office
1/1/10  A1    O1
1/1/10  A2    O2
1/1/10  A3    O3
```

So basically the tags should turn into column headers and must be populated. The column names should not be repeated so I can create a standard database table.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where is your Python code?

Comment: sorry -- code added. But the problem is to create a datarame as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

Consider nested xpath loops where first you loop through every `<SCRSGT>` nodes and then extract all SCRSGT's children using an inner dictionary that iteratively appends to a list for `DataFrame` call:

```
from lxml import etree as et
import pandas as pd

trees = et.parse('test.xml')

d = []
for srcsgt in trees.xpath('//SRCSGT'):     # ITERATE THROUGH ROOT'S CHILDREN
    inner = {}
    for elem in srcsgt.xpath('//*'):       # ITERATE THROUGH ROOT'S DESCENDANTS PER CHILD
        if len(elem.text.strip()) > 0:     # KEEP ONLY NODES WITH NON-ZERO LENGTH TEXT
            inner[elem.tag] = elem.text

    d.append(inner)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Output**

```
print(df)

#             ADDRESS                          AGENCY  ARCHDATE CLASSCOD  \
# 0  Jigjhgjas@va.gov  Department of Veterans Affairs  12172017        H   

#                                              CONTACT      DATE  \
# 0  COiyiyS, JUhhiuN<a href="mailto:Juggyui@va.gov...  11112017   

#                   DESC                                               LINK  \
# 0  CONTRACT SPECIALIST  https://www.fbo.gov/spg/VA/CaVAMC532/CaVAMC532...   

#                                         LOCATION   NAICS  \
# 0  Department of Veterans Affairs Medical Center  238210   

#                                               OFFADD            OFFICE  \
# 0  Department of Veterans Affairs;400 Fort Hill A...  Canandaigua VAMC   

#       PACKAGE RECOVERY_ACT  RESPDATE SETASIDE SOLNBR  \
# 0  Attachment            N  11172017      N/A   9069   

#                                              SUBJECT    ZIP  
# 0  H--3 YEAR TESTING/MAINTENANCE OF ELECTRICAL EQ...  14424
```